# Kafka Streams Session Windows with Punctuator

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm building a Kafka Streams application where I want to make use of Session Windows.

Say my session is configured as follows:

```java
// Inactivity gap is 5 seconds
// Grace period is 1 second
Duration inactivityGapDuration = Duration.ofSeconds(5);
Duration graceDuration         = Duration.ofSeconds(1);
KStream<Windowed<String>, EventData> windowedListKStream = groupedStream.windowedBy(
            SessionWindows.ofInactivityGapAndGrace(inactivityGapDuration, graceDuration))
    .aggregate(...)
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
    .toStream();
```

And given the following stream events:

| Event Key | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 12 |

Based on reading the docs and experiments I expect this will create 2 session windows: one with key **A** and one with key **B**.

Now say I receive this next event:

| Event Key | Time |
| --- | --- |
| B | 20 |

This will close the window with key **B**, *but the window with key A will remain open*. That is to say, when an event for a given key is received, only the stream time for the windows that have that key will advance. Is my understanding here correct?

If so, then this behavior is not exactly what I need. What I need is if I never see another event with key **A** then for the key **A** window to *eventually* close.

I think this is where the Punctuator can come in. However, if I read the docs correctly then I would need to basically re-implement the Session Window logic using the Processor API if I want to add a Punctuator. As far as I can tell I can't inject a Punctuator event into the session window DSL implementation in order to move the stream time along.

If all of the above is correct, then this seems like a big lift for what seems like a simple operation. Am I missing some other feature that would make this a simpler implementation?

Thank you!

Comment: This behaviour might be dependent on the partitions/tasks the events are routed in. Kafka Streams will create separate stores for each partition. If events A and B are not in the same partition, the window timestamp of A is not influenced by the B event. Can you elaborate on your setup with regards to that?

Comment: @KarstenSchnitter Session Windows are segregated by the event key. A session window will only close when a new event shows up for that session (so same key) with an event time > inactivity gap + grace period.

Through experiments I found that the kafka partition is unimportant;  it's the key that determines which session window the event goes to, which in turn drives the stream time and closing behavior for that window.

Answer (score 1):

> This will close the window with key B, but the window with key A will remain open. That is to say, when an event for a given key is received, only the stream time for the windows that have that key will advance. Is my understanding here correct?

Not totally correct. Stream-time is a per-partition (not per-key concept). Thus, if A and B are in the same partition, the second B record would indeed close both windows. If B is on a different partitions, the window of A won't be closed though.

> If so, then this behavior is not exactly what I need. What I need is if I never see another event with key A then for the key A window to eventually close.

It should be save to assume, that there will be data in all partitions, and thus the window would close eventually.